# Navigate back index on backbone router

Tags: backbone.js, routes

Trying figure out how to trigger an index route in Backbone.

```
routes:     
    '': 'home'    
    profile': 'init_profile'
```

and then in Chrome console..

```
app_router.navigate('', { trigger: true, replace: true });
```

Does not change URL or fire any callbacks.

However, the profile route works fine:

```
app_router.navigate('profile', { trigger: true, replace: true });
```

How do I trigger the index route?

Answer (score 1):

You should use just:

```
app_router.navigate('profile', true);
```

It should work that way.

Comment: But how do I trigger the
      ```'': 'home'``` route is my question.

Comment: I've tried what you posted, and it works for me the way I published it

Answer (score 1):

`Backbone.history.navigate('', true)`

Seems to work.